# Extending a Python class with the same name and return subclass instance

Tags: python, inheritance, swig

I have some Python classes being generated automatically using SWIG and I want to extend them.
The problem is, those classes have another method other than `__init__`, called `create` that returns a class instance (they are the real init).

I want to extend those classes with new methods but keep the original name.

**I tried to implement `__new__` method but it returns an instance of the parent class**

I get why it happens, but I can't seem to find a way to change it while keeping the `create` methods.

Let me show you an example with my **current implementation** attempt in order to explain:

File a:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        pass
    def create(self, ...):
        # do some stuff
        return object_of_A
```

File b:

```py
from a import A as AClass
class A(AClass):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        pass
    def __new__(cls, ...):
        # do some stuff
        return super(A, cls).create(...)
    def foo(self):
        print('Hi')
```

Wanted behavior:

```py
>>> from b import A
>>> a = A(...)
>>> a.foo()
>>> Hi
```

Actual behavior:

```py
>>> from b import A
>>> a = A(...)
>>> a.foo()
>>> AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should `create` be a classmethod? any reason you're calling `super` if your child class inherits `create`?

Comment: The common pattern for what I think you're trying to get at is to make `create` a classmethod, and inside the classmethod, it creates an instance using the type it recieves: `@classmethod create(cls, *args, **kwargs): return cls(*args, **kwargs)`. That way calling `child_class.create()` will return an instance of the correct class, and you can override `__init__` to handle any setup customization.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the code of `create`.  I can only re-write the code of the child class

Comment: does `child_cls.create()` rather than `super(cls).create()` return the correct type? that would indicate that it's already set-up that way correctly. (maybe for the sake of the question, don't name the child the same as the parent because naming is not the cause of the problem)

Comment: There is chance it solves the problem, I need to test it more, I'll update this thread :)

Comment: If you are building the library with a SWIG wrapper yourself, you could simple extend the generated python class using `%extend`

Comment: @JensMunk Well, It's a solution, but it involves writing a lot of Python code inside the *.i file which I don't want to.

Comment: I just tried the approach suggested by @Aaron. It works fine for me extending a class generated by SWIG. I simply called the parent constructor in my `__init__(self)` and added a few `@classmethod`s hiding the original class methods.

Comment: @JensMunk Can you write your full implementation?

Comment: Sure, I will post a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes a simple example. I have created a simple static method for creating objects in C++ and wrapped this with SWIG. Afterwards, I extend the class with the same name for changing the method slightly.

example.h

```
class A {
public:
  static int Create(A** obj);
  A() = default;
  ~A() = default;
  int test();
};
```

example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"

int A::test() {
  return 5;
}
int A::Create(A** obj) {
  *obj = new A();
  return 0;
}
```

example.i

```
%module example
%{
  #include "example.h"
%}

%typemap(in, numinputs=0) A **obj (A *temp) {
  $1 = &temp;
}

%typemap(argout) A ** {
  PyObject* temp = NULL;
  if (!PyList_Check($result)) {
    temp = $result;
    $result = PyList_New(1);
    PyList_SetItem($result, 0, temp);
  }

  // Create shadow object (do not use SWIG_POINTER_NEW)
  temp = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(*$1),
                            $descriptor(A*),
                            SWIG_POINTER_OWN | 0);

  PyList_Append($result, temp);
  Py_DECREF(temp);
}

%include "example.h"
```

setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name="example",
      py_modules=['example'],
      ext_modules=[Extension("_example",
                     ["example.i", "example.cpp"],
                     swig_opts=['-c++'],
                             extra_compile_args=['--std=c++11']
                             )]
)
```

extension.py

```
from example import A as parentA

class A(parentA):
  def __init__(self):
    super(A,self).__init__()
  def SmartMethod(self):
    return 2
  @staticmethod
  def Create():
      retval, obj = parentA.Create()
      obj.__class__ = A
      return obj
```

The new class defined in `extension.py` inherits all functionalities of the original (if any) and here an example of slightly changing the Create method.

The trick with changing the `__class__` attribute converts the new object into the descendant, so `SmartMethod` can be called. If you add additional members to the descendant, you must add these in the overloaded `Create` method.

Comment: Thank you Jens! Helped me a lot!
Any chance you can help me with something else? :)

Comment: Perhaps, we can do it in the chat

Comment: Great, can you send me a message? I can't send you

Comment: You profile is not public. I made mine public just now...

Comment: Still can't contact you :(